# Why is jReject not working right?

Tags: jquery, popup

I want to use jReject on my site.

I have added the code `$(function() { $.reject(); });` (line 51 in test page)

To test I add mse 10 to list of browsers and jReject should be showing for that browser.

[**Link on test page**](http://happyprezent.ru/CollectiveGift_template1.php)

But **jReject** is displaying:

[image: test]

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You did not include [jQuery Browser Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/) in your file. jReject depends upon it to detect the users browser. Link to the file in the head of your document before jReject. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too. That is because you haven't include .css file into your html page. Add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.reject.css" type="text/css" />
```

to your web page, where jquery.reject.css is downloaded from http://jreject.turnwheel.com/css/jquery.reject.css

Comment: had the same issue, adding the css file from jquery.reject and adding in the jquery.browser fixed the issue.